# Responsive navbar with logo image and fixed height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a fixed top navbar in my page, the navbar is set to an image with a fixed height and the navbar itself has a height, what i want to do is to vertically align the navbar brand logo with the list on the right side in large and responsive screens, how can i do that?
Here is my code:

```css
.navbar{
height:150px;
}

.navbar-brand img{
height:95px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<html>
<body><!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&text=Logo" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want the logo go below nav bar in mobile view?

Comment: @DanielH no i want them next to each other

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow @Heba, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as 
[Correct answe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `flex`. i have edited your snippet.

I have also written code for responsive behavior so that in small screen logo and toggle icon will also arrange properly.

i have used `height: auto !important` for `.navbar-brand` you can remove `!important` in your real code because it's not necessary. i wrote this only because in this snippet, bootstrap style is overriding my style.

for small screen remove height of `.navbar`

```
.navbar{
  height:auto;
}
```

if you need, you can use `min-height` instead. it's because bootstrap used collapse as static element not absolute, so the navbar will extend on menu open.

```css
.navbar{
height:150px;
}

.navbar-brand img{
height:95px;
}

.navbar > .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: auto !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  margin-left: auto;
  order: 2;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar > .container {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   }
   .navbar{
    height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<html>
<body><!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&text=Logo" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks perfect thank you, but can you check the navbar-collapse? there is something wrong with it

Comment: @Heba you can add `.navbar-collapse { background-color: yellow; }` to css to change the background color to whatever you want, currently is `transparent`

Comment: @DanielH your idea is also good but with content added, it won't look fine. so it's better to remove height as I suggested

Comment: @Lucian its perfect, thank you! but i have one more question, why did you remove the navbar-right from the ul? i want them to the right side not next to the logo

Comment: thank you. also don't forget to accept the answer for future reference

Comment: i didn't remove it. i copied it as your snippet. if you want it to the right, you can simply use `margin-left: auto` for `.navbar`